# Easier way for button information submits (secure)

Tags: php, mysqli

When using a button to submit an information which is prepared but you want to add a something like title to the button, so the "value" with form like :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="Man" value="Man">
</form>
```

With the php code like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['Man'])) {

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

     $sql = "
     UPDATE users
     SET gender = ?
     WHERE username = ?
 ";

 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['Man'], $_SESSION['username']);
 $ok = $stmt->execute();

    if ($ok == TRUE) {
        echo "<font color='#00CC00'>Your gender has been updated.</font><p>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " .$stmt->error;
    }
}
```

This is the code, which so many people using (normal easy  code with prepared statements) but there is a one mistake... If somebody change the value of **Man** to eg. **lol** , the gender in database will be set to "lol" because the value is "lol"...
I noticed this problem in so many websites and codes here, and so the way to fix this, is to pre-define the $_POST... Check answer

Answer (score 0):

**You need to whitelist the allowed values in an array**

```
if (isset($_POST['Man'])) {

$allowed_values=array("Man","Women");

if(!in_array($_POST['Man'],$allowed_values)){
echo"error message";
die();
}

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

     $sql = "
     UPDATE users
     SET gender = ?
     WHERE username = ?
 ";

 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['Man'], $_SESSION['username']);
 $ok = $stmt->execute();

    if ($ok == TRUE) {
        echo "<font color='#00CC00'>Your gender has been updated.</font><p>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " .$stmt->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't  $_POST['Man'] = Man; easier?

Comment: if there will be more than one options (submit buttons) to select then what you will do? If the form will be like this <form action="" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="Man" value="Man">
<input type="submit" name="Man" value="Women">
</form>

Comment: In this case I'd create obviously another input <input type="submit" name"Woman" value="Woman"> and then to define it by $_POST['Woman'] = Woman; easier..

Comment: In the database  there is only one field for gender

Comment: yes of course.. but you probably don't understand it huh? you will have only TWO options in buttons (Man and Woman) so $_POST['Man'] = Man; and $_POST['Woman'] = Woman; .. One or another .. what do you mean there is only on field for gender? it will UPDATE GENDER... Did you read my question?

Answer (score -1):

One simple thing to do is to pre-define the $_POST so the value will never be changed...
with simple one line code :

```
$_POST['Man'] = Man;
```

By adding this code to your code, the value cannot be changed with html so 
the result wll be still the "Man" and you are good to go.

Comment: Magically changed superglobals are terrible to debug.

Comment: Why would you want to debug this?

Comment: You don't see the usefulness of debugging code? You set the superglobal somewhere in some file. In the same request in some totally unrelated file I check the contents of the supergobal and will think WTF I just posted `Vrouw` and suddenly somehow the superglobal contains `Man` instead.

Comment: This post is about buttons which have defined what they will write into database!

Comment: Doesn't matter. Manually changing the superglobals is terrible practice for reasons I just tried to explain to you.

Comment: this is ONLY for buttons... so for other cases you can do  it by your way, this is way which is pretty easy